# Somehow I lost push notifications in my app. I cant figure it out

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, entitlements

I have push notifications as part of my provisioning profile.

I have remote notifications and push notifications selected as my capabilities for all build types.

Is there anything else I need to do?  When I build my app now I don't even see notifications available in the app settings.  It's just gone completely.

I'm using react native btw.. dont think it matters but just throwing that in there.  I feel like I'm missing one of those deep buried settings.

I've tried deleting and reinstalling app.  restarting phone.  cleaning project.  removing and re-adding the capabilities.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of remote notifications: background update notifications(those whose payload contains a `content-available: 1`) and regular push notification. The former type is always silent and the user will see nothing, and the latter is where the user received a message on the lock screen.

For an iOS app, the background update notification is ALWAYS allowed without the user having to grant you any permissions. Only when you want to deliver notifications where the user will be alerted, will the user have to grant you the permission first. Therefore, when you enable the capabilities, you are telling the system that your app should be receiving notifications, but the system does not know which type, so it allows you to register to APNS and receive notifications in the background. Only doing this much means your user will see no alert prompting them to allow your app to send notifications and there will be no notification settings for your app -- the user can't turn off something they don't even know about.

In order to prompt your user to grant you permission, see the permission settings in the Settings app, and be able to deliver notifications with sounds and messages, you must, at some point in your code, ask the system for such permissions using the following code:

iOS 9:

`UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil))`

then implement `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegister notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings)` in your App Delegate yo check if the user has granted you the permission. (Check if `notificationSettings.types` is empty. If it is, the user has denied it).

iOS 10 & beyond:

```
import UserNotifications

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { granted in
    if (granted) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

When you execute these code, the system will immediately present an alert to the  user asking them to give or deny your app the permission to present notifications that can contain an alert, a sound, and display a badge on your app icon. After making a selection, the user can go into the Settings app and review/change their selection, where you will now see your app has a notifications setting.

P.S. As the user can later revise and change their notifications settings to your app, you should never store the granted status in your app. Rather, use the proper APIs the get the current status each time you need it. For iOS 9, check is `UIApplication.shared.currentUserNotificationSettings?.types` is empty(empty meaning you have no permission), and on iOS 10 & above use `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in ... }` to check if the settings contain any types at all. Optionally, calling `requestAuthorization` could also directly return you the granted boolean value, and if the user has been alerted and made a choice, the `requestAuthorization` method will directly give you the user's choice without asking them again.

**TL;DR** You haven't asked the user for permissions yet. They will not see the permission alert, and you will not find a notification settings for your app in the Settings app until you've done so.